# subquery X temp table X dynamic sql X table valued function

Tags: sql-server, performance, subquery, dynamic-sql, table-variable

I have a view that summarizes a lot of info for my items. Let's call it v_item_details.

This view is defined via recursive cte's, and can become very slow if the right filtering is not applied. Basically, if I provide a list of item id's, things run smoothly. So something like `SELECT * FROM v_item_details WHERE item_id IN(1,2,3)` runs in under 1 second.

Things get complicated when I try to fetch the item details for a group of items that is defined in another table. The query `SELECT * FROM v_item_details WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM items WHERE group_id = 1)` will take over 1 minute, even though group_id is indexed and the subquery returns the same item_id's as the previously query (1,2 and 3).

I tried to create a table variable and insert the results of the subquery in it, and then do a join on that, but it still took over 1 minute.

Next I tried to wrap my view with a table valued function that receives the item_id as the parameter and then do a cross apply, to try and force the execution of the same plan as the simple select, but that took over 4 minutes!

Right now I'm using a dynamic query that selects the ids and then executes the fast subquery. But that's suboptimal, because now I'm stuck with stored procedures, and not views that I could manipulate further.

Any thoughts on how to force SQL to first select the values in the subquery and then run the fast subquery? I thought that using a LOOP join query hint would work, but it didn't, because although it did do a loop starting with the subquery, the query plan for the view was not the same as the fast query, so I still had the performance issue.

Best regards,
Carlos Jourdan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to have a live example that we can build on our own SQL Server instance to reproduce and diagnose the problem.  In the absence of that, here are a few things I might try:

- Ensure that statistics on the `items` table are up-to-date
- Try using a JOIN rather than IN clause (I know these should generally be the same, but they behave very differently in certain cases, such as with COLUMNSTORE indexes, so maybe there are quirks with recursive CTEs as well)
- Ensure that the table(s) used in `vw_item_details` have the proper primary key and/or indexes
- Try selecting only the columns you need rather than * from `vw_item_details` (a long-shot, but you never know...)